# Quartus II hangs when trying to create new project

Tags: linux, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I have Quartus II installed under Ubuntu 13.10. It starts up fine, but when I click "finish" on the "Create New Project" wizard, it loads infinitely, stuck at 0%, then stops responding.

I have tried this in both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions, with the same results from both. Anyone know what might be causing the issue, or how to figure out what is causing the program to freeze?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software tech support.

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by choosing the project directory to some where else that with my user account I have enough permission R/W files there.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was creating the project in the directory where Quartus II was installed. The software did not hang in any other location.

Comment: I has been almost six years, and the problem remains :))) Even after Altera acquisition

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure that Quartus didn't pop up a window that is hidden behind one of your windows?

I had this problem recently with the Quartus programmer.  I thought it was hung and I kept killing the process until I noticed in the taskbar there was an additional window.  When I clicked on it, it brought the window to the foreground, I hit "OK" and everything was fine.  Still don't know why the window always showed up in the background.

Comment: I don't see any additional windows. Also I get the "process is not responding" message when I try to close Quartus.

Comment: Are you trying to create the project on a local or network drive?  If on a network drive, do you see the same behavior when using a local drive?

Comment: I was trying to create the project in the same place where Quartus II was installed. (home folder) For some reason I just tried to create the project on my secondary hard drive and it worked.

Comment: The CAD tools that we use are used by a relatively small number of people so the software usually hasn't been debugged very thoroughly. Glad that it's working for you.